# Smoothly animate attribute changes to ~3000 Raphael objects at once

Tags: javascript, svg, visualization, raphael

**UPDATED QUESTION**
I've updated this to be a little more succinct..:

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pX2Xb/4/ I have some raphael code that draws 3000 circles to a page. It then attempts to animate all circles at once (changes fill colour) over 10 seconds, which results in a clunky visual animation. Change the number of circles to 20 to see a much smoother animation for comparison.

My questions are (a) is it possible for me to make the update to the 3000 elements smoother and (b) if so, what does the code to do that look like?

Some notes:

- I'm willing to take a small timing hit if there's some way to optimise around this, but, for example, I would like *all* circles to at least have updated in 1.5x whatever the animation time is set to. So, if animation is 10 seconds, all circles should have changed in 15.
- 3000 elements is roughly my limit at the moment, so I'd be happy with it working for that :) In saying that, if a solution can effectively handle more than that, for a general case, that'd be really great.

**older details, in case it helps**

I'm creating a large map of US counties, of which there are over 3000; I'm using [this Wikipedia svg file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aUSA_Counties_with_FIPS_and_names.svg) to get the relevant SVG paths to create the map, and am rendering the map using [RaphaelJs](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Accordingly, I end up with over 3000 statements similar to the following:

```
    var cc_02130 = rsr.path("M 140.66674,.... 320.11635"); // county path
    cc_02130.attr({id: '02130',.. .."marker-start": 'none'}); // init attrs
```

I'm also creating a `Paper.set()` object to hold all of these elements:

```
var myset = paper.set([cc_56039, cc_56040, cc_56041 ...])
```

Forgetting for a moment that the file actually generated here is quite large, I would very much appreciate suggestions of *how I can apply changes to the volume of objects detailed above, that is both quick and reasonably ok CPU wise* (possible a big ask).

I'm definitely open to changing the structure of my code/objects, as long as I can individually change attributes of specific counties.
 For example, I would like to be able to apply a different colour to each path content in a second or two (for all 3000+).

The challenge I'm facing is not how to apply the colour changes, animations, etc, but how to do this quickly and efficiently. Right now, my machine screams at me if I loop and apply changes over the 3000+ objects; as an alternative, I was using `setTimeout` to break the changes out into smaller chunks (maybe 10 at a go, with a 40 ms delay). Over 3000 items, this becomes quite slow, and still uses a lot of CPU.

Thanks,
oli

Comment: My guess is that your delay comes from the large number of redraws that are triggered by you updating the objects, not from the change to the object itself. 3000 function calls should be very doable within a second even on slow machines. Can you measure if you are triggering a redraw for each change?

If you are, then see if there is a way to block redraws or do batch updates before redrawing.

Comment: I agree @Munter - I now understand my issue to be to do with the actual redrawing/rendering of all of these shapes, as opposed to the actual function call. With this in mind, I'm still somewhat ensure as to how I can improve _this_ issue. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Your kind of problem is better suited for d3.js, if you can afford to lose non svg browsers. Here is your jsfiddle with the animation handled by d3: http://jsfiddle.net/ekMd6/

Comment: @Duopixel wow - thank you very much. that's very interesting - it's certainly a seamless transition between the colours. I'm only learning about SVG: Do you know how the implementations are different that makes d3 so smooth? and could this be implemented with standard Raphael?

Comment: @Duopixel I should also add - what about the case where I only want to update a subset of circle elements? My original issue was regarding paths, of which I may not want to update all of them. Is there any way I can hold an array of the elements and update these as smoothly, or is the benefit of your example based on not iterating over an array and performing animations individually as I do so (i.e.: you improve by using '#canvas circle' to reference all circles)?. I understand that my updated question/jsfiddle may not have explained this, so if it's out of scope, feel free to tell me.

Comment: I don't know anything about each animation implementation, I'm just an enthusiast of both libraries. Here is an implementation where you can convert a Raphael set into a d3 selection: http://jsfiddle.net/mFecs/

Comment: @Duopixel thanks for this, definitely the best I've gotten so far. Ideally, for the sake of the question, I'd love to know how this could be done either with straight Raphael, or as a purely js addition to the library (it would be good if this functionality could exist without needing a whole other library). I will add that d3 looks amazing, and I'm going to do my next project with it :), but doing this in Raphael should be possible I feel. If you'd be able to put your comments above into a response below I can award the bounty when time is up if there are no other suggestions from you/others.

Comment: This is a little smoother and just uses Raphael: http://jsfiddle.net/phil_mcc/6q57B/3/

Comment: Thanks @philmccull - it's brilliant to see a straight javascript/Raphael implementation in here. Ultimately, I went with Duopixel's answer due to it's scalability (for example, bumping up circles to 5000-10000 shows no noticeable impact on the animation), but I'm glad that this is here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why, but [D3.js](http://d3js.org) is more efficient when animating a large number of elements at once. You can make them both work seamlessly by creating a Raphael function that receives a set and returns the html objects you want to animate:

```
Raphael.st.nodes = function() {
  var elements = [];
  this.forEach(function (i) {
     elements.push(i.node);
  });
  return elements;
}
```

And then you let d3 take it from there

```
//circleholder is a Raphael set
elements = circleholder.nodes()
d3.selectAll(elements)
  .transition()
  .attr("fill", function(d,i){return colours[randomNum(14)]})
  .duration(ANIMATION_DELAY)
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mFecs/

Comment: Very nifty example of using D3 with Raphael. Definitely an idea I'll be stealing for future projects!

Comment: @slebetman are you aware that stealing code is against the terms of use of StackOverflow?

Comment: Thanks @Duopixel really appreciate your multiple inputs in to this. I'll be using your implementation - at this point, I'm considering just reimplementing it all in d3, but we'll see - either way, I'll definitely use the library in the future - so thank you!

Comment: @ajax333221 In SO ideas are meant to be stolen, actual code is licensed under CC. Even then, in my native language "to steal" often means "inspired by" and I'm sure that's what slebetman meant :)

Comment: @Duopixel well, you might be right, but 'steal' is a strong word, I think it suggest it is not planning to give contribution. But whatever, :)

Comment: Raphaël doesn’t create separate `setInterval`. It’s already uses `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: tried with no luck to use d3.js Force Layout with Raphael drawn circles.  [My code](http://jsfiddle.net/brockness/pagHh/)

Comment: The jsfiddle is out of date (d3 library has moved). Working link as of 12/2014 http://jsfiddle.net/mFecs/16/

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not currently that familiar with Rapael.js, I'd just suggest, in a generic JavaScript manner, that you could maybe create an changeRaphaelPathAttributeEvent, that you'd emit each time you'd like to change the paths, with the attribute changes as arguments to said event. And then attach event handlers to each of the paths that would carry out the attribute change, if that's possible.

That way, you would get around the problem of having a loop access all the paths variables and change the attributes synchronously (which would directly affect the page's responsiveness while processing); the method would have a lower impact on the performance that the user experiences.

Note: This is just a solution to get around the immediate performance hit. Maybe there are other solutions available of minimizing the amount of objects needed to access, that you should also consider (and that I'm not capable of telling you, as I don't know Raphael that well).

Comment: Thanks @Sune, I'm attempting to implement this right now. I haven't got it going yet, however, I'm concerned that it will still suffer from the same problem, which is the browser attempting to apply changes to all of these svg objects in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write all the paths manually? I think is better if you put all the paths in an object. Then you can iterate the object and draw all the paths using, for example, `for in`. In that process you can give an internal ID to every path using `element.id = 'name'`. Once you have all the internal ID´s and the paths drawed, you can use the getById method: `getById('pathId')` If you are going to use Sets I recommend you to use Clousures, you can first declare the variables

```
var setName = Paper.Set()
```

and then push the paths in another loop

```
for (countie in Lousiana){
    setName.push(countie)
}
```

Then you have methods like `Paper.forEach()` if you want to apply some attributes to the elements. Or `Set.FotEach()`. Both take a callback function like argument, and then executes that function in each iteration.

If you want to share your code it wouldn´t be a problem for me to  check it out and give  my opinion on how to solve some of the situations. I´m also working with maps, I´m developing an Educative Video Game, if you want I can also share my code with you, there aren´t that much documentation about Raphael, so it would be useful for me to see how are you using it and maybe the same for you.

Bye!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've implemented much of what you mentioned now (especially liked the nifty element.id/getById stuff - didn't know you could do that). Unfortunately I'm still have an issue speeding things up, but will post code here soon.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, changing the attributes of 3000 items should be easy for any computer. <strike>Raphael uses a setInterval for each animated element. After the element's attribute is changed, the browser re-draws the entire page. This is 2999 un-necessary re-draws.</strike>

Here is what I would do: Instead of using the Raphael animation, use a loop to change each element. It is a little more complex, but it is faster. In addition, you can change the steps per second. If your animation is running too slow, just reduce the steps per second.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dqJps/25/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Joel. I didn't get a chance to try this as I'm not sure how I can apply it across the board (for example, using the animate function, which gradually changes an attribute over time). I've updated my question accordingly, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: The redraw doesn't happen until the javascript code stops executing (the browser enters the event loop) so calling 3000 `changeAttribute()` in a loop will only cause one redraw.

Comment: @slebetman - I agree with what you are saying, but my point is that Raphael sets 3000 setIntervals. The changes are never in a loop. When each interval finishes, the browser detects a HTML change and re-draws the page (or the relevant parts of the page).

Comment: Raphaël doesn’t create 3000 setIntervals.